# Migrating user files, docs, etc. between XP machines

Tags: windows-xp, migration, user-profiles

In 'moving' from one machine to another, I have backed up desktop, my documents, and .pst files.  Am I missing anything significant, considering the user only really used Office and the browser?

Comment: Browser settings (saved logins/passwords) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For moving user account from one computer to another I use [User Profile Wizard 3.0](http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html) and it works great.
IT moves all documents,setting for your application if you want, explorer settings, start menu, ...
and is simple. I used it many times without problem when migrating desktops to domain.

Comment: Looks interesting